# Upper bound on weighted sum of symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality, geometric-inequalities

For an engineering problem, I need to be able to bound from above the maximum eigenvalue of the following quantity:
$$\lambda_\max\left(\sum^{N}_{i=1} w_i A_i\right)$$
where $w_i \in \mathbb{R}, i= 1,\ldots,N$ are some real (not positive in general) coefficients, $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, i = 1, \ldots, n$ are symmetric, indefinite in general (actually, their leading eigenvalue *can* be positive or negative; the others are all negative), full-rank matrices, for which I already know (as given prior information) that:
$$\lambda_\max\left(\sum^{N}_{i=1} A_i\right) < C, C > 0$$
I was wondering if there is any known way to make any norm of the sequence $\{w_i\}^N_{i=1}$ appear in an upper bound, *i.e.*, to show that $$ \lambda_\max\left(\sum^{N}_{i=1} w_i A_i\right) \lesssim f(\|w\|_p,C)$$ with $\|w\|_p$ the $p$-norm of the vector $w = \{w_i\}^N_{i=1}$ and $C$ given above.

Of course for $A_i$ symmetric and positive-semidefinite matrices, and positive $w$ the solution should be easy (by saturating the sum with $\|w\|_{\infty}$).

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider the matrix 
$$
A_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & u
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $u < 0$, and the one-term sum $\omega_1 A_1$. In this case, $\lambda_{max} = 1$, so we can pick $C = 1$.

Now picking $\omega_1 = -1$, we get
$$
\lambda_{max}(\omega_1 A_1) = -u,
$$
where $u$ is an arbitrary negative number. So you can certainly make it larger than $f(1, 1)$ no matter what $f$ you pick.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the counterexample. If you look at the problem in terms of singular values, it would seem that you can say $\sigma_\max(\omega_1 A_1) \leq |\omega_1| \sigma_\max(A_1) =  |\omega_1| \max \{|u|, 1\}$. I guess you can still apply the triangle inequality w.r.t. the spectral norm and say that $\|\sum_i w_i A_i\|_2 \leq \sum_i \|w\|_\infty \|A_i\|_2$ right? (the latter norm denoting the spectral norm)

Comment: I'll be honest: most of what you just said means nothing to me. I"m just good at finding basic counterexamples in linear algebra. :) Perhaps someone better at the vocabulary of analysis can say something useful about your comment.